# scrartcl hyperref not working

Tags: hyperref, koma-script

`hyperref` doesn't work inside `scrartcl` class. It happens when I use that class and I want to link to another page but doesn't work at all. Any help? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
pagesize,
headinclude=false,
footinclude=false,
hyperref=true
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[pdftitle=learnChinese,pdfauthor=yu,
colorlinks=true, urlcolor=magenta, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\paperwidth=4cm
\paperheight=4cm
\typearea{100}

\pagecolor{LightCyan2}


\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\Huge

\clearpage
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\begin{center}
\hyperref[o]{あ}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{2.5}}

\newpage
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\begin{center}
い 
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{2.5}}

\clearpage
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\begin{center}
う
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{2.5}}

\clearpage
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\begin{center}
え
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{2.5}}

\clearpage
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\begin{center}
お \label{o}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{2.5}}


\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

When you run the MWE, you will see you can't go to the fifth page after click on the first page's character.

Comment: I can not imagine any conflicts right now. Can you please post  some codes as your Minimal Working Example ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add the code of a small complete LaTeX document to your question (using the `edit` button left below your current post) that illustrates your problem? It will us help to analyze the problem (which will not be possible without the example document).

Comment: The format is very bad after I pasted my code example, sorry if you have some difficulties reading the code. Thanks for your help, I didn't realize you guys replied me soon after I posted my question, it was so quick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem has nothing to to with `scrartcl` but rather with a misunderstanding of `\label`, so let me boil it down to the bare minimum. Consider the following code

```
% WRONG CODE
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ref{bla} How \newpage
are \newpage
you? \label{bla}
\end{document}
```

A label points to the last item (chapter, section, equation, figure ...) with some *counter* which has been increased by `\refstepcounter`. If you look at the `aux` file generated by the above code, you'll find

```
\newlabel{bla}{{}{3}}
```

so a label on page three referencing nothing. Using `\hyperref` will result in a link pointing nowhere, which becomes in this case (by default? I honestly don't know) the document start.

If you want to create internal links and targets within your document you have at least two possibilities: the first is to use the `\phantomsection` macro, which basically provides a hidden counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\hyperref[bla]{How} \newpage
are \newpage
you? \phantomsection\label{bla}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you may use the `\hyperlink`/`\hypertarget` pair of commands

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\hyperlink{bla}{How} \newpage
are \newpage
\hypertarget{bla}{you?}
\end{document}
```